# how to use 3 functions that return an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

hey guys so i'm a beginning of javascript and I have a question... I have 3 functions let's say:

```
const a = (x, y, z) => {
 return {x, y, z}
}

const b = (a, b, c) => {
 return {a, b, c}
}

const c = (d, e, f) => {
 return {d, e, f}
}
```

let's say I want to make use of these return values in another function, so..

```
   const p = () => {
   const arr = [returned value from function a, returned value from function b, returned value from function c]
return arr
    }
```

how would I somehow use the objects that functions a, b, c in order to return an array of objects from function p?

thank you!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to provide an example of what the result of calling `p()` should look like? Explain what your inputs are, expected outputs and actual results you get from your code. How are the results different to what you expect?

Comment: hi phil. I just want to somehow access the object values that each of the functions return from a, b, and c, and somehow get those values out into function p. is this possible? so basically, i'm storing each argument in functions a, b, and c into objects and wanting to access them in function p. I hope this clarifies the confusion from my post.

Comment: Was there anything unclear in my comment? You seem to have misunderstood what was asked of you

Comment: no there was nothing unclear in your comment. all I wanted to know was, if function p, which takes no arguments, can somehow access the returned values from functions a, b, and c. so basically, could I make an array based off the returned object values from functions a, b, and c? in other words, can I use the returned values from functions a, b, and c in function p? would it be possible for function p to hold an array of objects based off what is returned from functions a, b, and c?

Comment: You keep writing comments instead of [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71596800/edit) with examples of the result you want 

Comment: phil I have updated my post to the best that I can. if you can help, it would be much appreciated. the returned value from function P would the returned values from function a,b, and c. is it possible to do it? I am just a beginning of javascript....

Comment: Where do you expect to call functions `a`, `b` and `c`? Before calling `p()` or within `p`? If the latter, what values should be passed to each?

Comment: functions a, b, and c are called separately and all called before function p(). my main question is, will p() be able to some how get the values that are returned from function a, b, and c? so if I run functions, a, b, and c first... will function p be able to obtain the returned values from those 3 functions and use those values (in this example) as an array of objects?

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work. If not, please update your question with your actual attempt so we can help debug any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Following what you have asked:

```
const result1 = a(1, 'dog', null)
// result1 would be { x: 1, y: 'dog', z: null }

const result2 = b('cat', 2, null)
// result1 would be { a: 'cat', b: 2, c: null }

const result3 = c(3, 4, 'pig')
// result3 would be { d: 3, e: 4, f: 'pig' }
```

Therefore if you made the p function:

```
const p = () => {
    return [ a(1, 'dog', null), b('cat', 2, null), c(3, 4, 'pig') ]
}

const result1 = p()
// result1 would be: 
// [ 
//   { x: 1, y: 'dog', z: null }, 
//   { a: 'cat', b: 2, c: null }, 
//   { d: 3, e: 4, f: 'pig' } 
// ]
```

It would be far more likely that p would take some kind of arguments, then would use them inside.  For example:

```
const p = (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
     return [ a(arg1, arg2, arg3), b(arg1, arg2, arg3), c(arg1, arg2, arg3) ]
}

const result2 = p(1, 'dog' null)
// result2 would be:
// [ 
//   { x: 1, y: 'dog', z: null }, 
//   { a: 1, b: 'dog', c: null }, 
//   { d: 1, e: 'dog', f: null } 
// ]
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const one = (a, b, c) => {
  return {a, b, c};
}

const two = (a, b, c) => {
  return {a, b, c};
}

const three = (a, b, c) => {
  return {a, b, c};
}

const result = () => {
  let firstObj = one(10,20,30);
  let secondObj = two(40,50,60);
  let thirdObj = three(70,80,90);
  // Returns all of the objects in an array.
  return [firstObj, secondObj, thirdObj];
}

console.log(result());
```